# authentication with firebase Realtime Database without user

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase realtime database with read/write to all, however I don't have any user and don't intend to auth user. The data is written by a event listener and scheduler(java), my html ui application supposed to read data only.

How should I do to secure my db?

With development(unsecure) mode, I can use any http client to write/read data? How do I pass authentication after I secure it?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to protect against. Instead of saying what you don't want (the user signing in), can you tell us what you do want to protect the data from?

Comment: I want to restrict read only from html ui application, and write access from my backend application. Can I setup a static access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow only your web site to read, and only your backend to write, you'll want to combine security rules with Firebase App Check.

#### Security rules

First in security rules, you'll do:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

This allows everyone to read your entire database (we'll limit it to your app later), and allows nobody with a client-side SDK to write to it.

I strongly recommend adding some additional logic in the rules to limit how people can read the data though. For example, if your code first reads a list of users, and then shows the posts from a selected user, modify your rules to only allow that specific path, and reject anything else.

#### App Check

Now with the rules in place, you'll want to start using App Check to reduce the abuse you get from people taking your configuration data and calling the API on their own.

App Check is no guarantee that this can't happen anymore (especially on web), but it definitely increases the work a malicious user has to do.

Comment: How can I update the data then? with .write false. I am using curl to invoking update.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that "from my backend application" meant through one of our Admin SDKs. If there is such an SDK for your platform, I'd recommend using that as they run with elevated privileges that bypass the security rules. If there is no such SDK, you can either use an OAuth2 token of a collaborator with database edit permission (in the console) to write the data, or you can sign in to Firebase Authentication on your backend, and then hard-code the UID of that user in the rules: `".write": "auth.uid === 'uidOfYourServerUser'"`

Comment: Is there a document for this? I tried to generate a custom token from admin SDK, however I am geting 401 while using it. Tried to add it to http header 

Authorization Bearer token

but no luck to make it work.

Comment: beside, am I able to update data via admin sdk? didn't find relevant document for that either.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data?

Comment: thanks for that, I guess using curl to update data is not allowed once I set .write to false

Comment: "[With the REST API] you can either use an OAuth2 token of a collaborator with database edit permission (in the console) to write the data, or you can sign in to Firebase Authentication on your backend, and then hard-code the UID of that user in the rules". ¯\_(ツ)_/¯